# Writing NDEF message with PN532

Tags: python, nfc, ndef, pn532

I am currently trying to write an NDEF message (for example [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) with a PN532 board, utilizing the ndeflib library. I can read and write the blocks.

However when I tap any of the card with my phone the website won't open. I have analyzed the protocol as well as asked chatgpt to decode the block I am writing (block 6) - and it seems to be OK, still doesn't work tho.

Could you please give me some insights or ideas what am I doing wrong here?

I'll below attach the code I am using:

```
import adafruit_pn532.spi as PN532_SPI
import adafruit_pn532.adafruit_pn532
from digitalio import DigitalInOut
import board
import busio
import ndef
import time


def write_url_ndef_message(url):
    # Set up SPI communication with the PN532 NFC module
    spi = busio.SPI(board.SCK, board.MOSI, board.MISO)
    cs_pin = DigitalInOut(board.D5)
    pn532 = PN532_SPI.PN532_SPI(spi, cs_pin, debug=False)

    # Configure PN532 to communicate with NFC tags
    pn532.SAM_configuration()

    ic, ver, rev, support = pn532.firmware_version
    print("Found PN532 with firmware version: {0}.{1}".format(ver, rev))

    print("Waiting for RFID/NFC card to write to!")

    key = b"\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"

    uri_record = ndef.UriRecord(iri=url)

    # Create an NDEF message with the URI record
    ndef_message = [uri_record]

    # Convert the NDEF message to bytes
    ndef_message_bytes = b''.join(ndef.message_encoder(ndef_message))

    print(f"printing the message created from the UriRecord: {ndef_message}")

    # Ensure the NDEF message is 16 bytes long (pad if necessary)
    if len(ndef_message_bytes) < 16:
        ndef_message_bytes += b'\x00' * (16 - len(ndef_message_bytes))

    print("length of the ndef message byte array is: ", len(ndef_message_bytes))
    print(f"printing the encoded message: {ndef_message_bytes}")

    while True:
        print('Place the card on the board...')
        uid = pn532.read_passive_target(timeout=0.5)
        # Try again until a card is available.
        if uid is not None:
            break
        else:
            time.sleep(1)

    print("Found card with UID:", [hex(i) for i in uid])

    block_to_write = 6

    print(f"Authenticating block {block_to_write}...")

    authenticated = pn532.mifare_classic_authenticate_block(uid, block_to_write,
                                                            adafruit_pn532.adafruit_pn532.MIFARE_CMD_AUTH_B,
                                                            key)

    if not authenticated:
        print("Authentication failed!")
    else:
        print(f'Authentication for block {block_to_write} has been successful')

    print(f"Now writing block {block_to_write}...")
    # Write 16 byte block.
    pn532.mifare_classic_write_block(block_to_write, ndef_message_bytes)

    print(
        f"Wrote to block {block_to_write}, now trying to read that data:",
        [hex(x) for x in pn532.mifare_classic_read_block(block_to_write)],
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    write_url_ndef_message("google.com")
```

I should also always pad the byte array to be exactly 16 bytes otherwise the write operation fails. What happens if the URL is more than 16 bytes? I know it is possible to write an NDEF message along multiple blocks but did not find much information about it, and I am even struggling with interpreting one block... Thank you in advance for your support!

Comment: Unfortunately a Mifare Classic Card does not actually conform to a NFC Standard Type, it is a proprietary format with a proprietary encoding of Ndef on top of the card format. Thus it is not guaranteed that every phone will be able to read Ndef from a Mifare Classic Card. You don't specify your phone hardware so it's difficult to tell if your phone can read what you have written. I suggest you use an App like NXP's TagWriter to write the same data and then check your phone can read it correctly without an App.

Comment: @Andrew hey, thank you for your quick reply! It is interesting what you say, because I am using an iPhone14 and with a dedicated app (nfc tools) I also can not read or write the card, HOWEVER if I open up the iPhone automation tool where you can pair nfc tags to automated actions, the phone immediately recognises the card and it does indeed work. So I assume the problem is not with the card as the connection between the device and the nfc tag has been established already.

Comment: Here the first block and the 6th (with the ndef google message)

Block 0: ['0x65', '0x82', '0x22', '0x26', '0xe3', '0x8', '0x4', '0x0', '0x3', '0x57', '0xb0', '0x2a', '0x86', '0xf4', '0x99', '0x90']
...
...
Block 6: ['0xd1', '0x1', '0xb', '0x55', '0x0', '0x67', '0x6f', '0x6f', '0x67', '0x6c', '0x65', '0x2e', '0x63', '0x6f', '0x6d', '0x0']

Comment: iOS 13.0+ should be able to read and write to Mifare Classic Tags (so could be a Tag problem if you cannot read/write to it), it tends to be more that Some Android don't support it because it is not an NFC standard. Because of it's status I stay away from Mifare Classic Tag, I suggest you read https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN1305.pdf on how Ndef is stored on a Mifare Classic Tag.